# Using regexp namespace from EXSLT in browser console causes a SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox, xpath

I want to use regexp namespace in my XPath expressions when searching elements in browser console, but get `SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.` trying to do so.

I followed http://help.dottoro.com/ljspsvcs.php as a tutorial for creating a namespace resolver.

Here's my code:

```
function nsResolver (nsPrefix) {
    if (nsPrefix == "regexp") {
        return "http://exslt.org/regular-expressions";
    }
    return null;
}
document.evaluate('//a[regexp:test(@href, "qwerty-[\d]+$")]', document.documentElement, nsResolver, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that someone has defined a set of extension functions in a particular namespace does not mean that every XSLT processor supports those functions. What is wrong here is that you are using an ancient XSLT processor that has not been upgraded in years (because the browser vendors lost interest in the XML user community).

Consider installing Saxon-JS, which provides XSLT 3.0 running in the browser, with built-in regular expression support according to W3C specifications. (Disclaimer: it's my company's product).